# how to get count of values in redis hash?

Tags: redis

i got a redis hash eg

```
key field value

1000 state "ca" 
1000 zip "95054"
2000 state "ca" 
2000 zip "95050"
3000 state "ny" 
3000 zip "12345"
```

how can i answer questions like how many state are "CA" . i need to do count of values for a field. is it possible ? help would be appreciated.

-Avi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to store a separate count for the unique values. You can get the length of a single hash, but not when you in this case got three different keys.

command key field value

> HSET 1000 state "ca"
>
> HSET 1000 zip "95054"
>
> INCR ca
>
> HSET 2000 state "ca"
>
> HSET 2000 zip "95050"
>
> INCR ca
>
> HSET 3000 state "ny"
>
> HSET 3000 zip "12345"
>
> INCR ny

If you want to get how many hash keys with state "ca" use:

> GET ca

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are in charge of inserting values in the hash, then use MULTI/EXEC to wrap hash insertions and appropriate INCRS.  So take ptzOn's approach but don't forget to wrap it all up in MULTI/EXEC to have atomic semantics.  Do the same thing on hash deletes and use a DECR.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the data above is a list of cities.  Really, you might consider storing these like...

```
key              value
city:1000:state  "ca"
city:1000:zip    "95054"
city:2000:state  "ca"
city:2000:zip    "95050"
```

Now back to your question... In SQL, you might want to do something like: SELECT Count(*) FROM cities WHERE state='CA'.  Or maybe if you wanted the count for each state... SELECT state, COUNT(*) FROM cities GROUP BY state.

In my opinion, this is something that Redis struggles with a bit, but it gives you the ability to re-think your database design.  If you plan on executing a query like this one a lot, consider creating a new Sorted Set of states.  The score would be your count in this case.  Use **ZINCRBY** on this set (let's call it city_count_by_state) when you add/remove records to/from your cities "table".  Now your query is something like: **ZRANK** city_count_by_state 'CA'.  Adding/removing/getting rank on a sorted set runs in O(log(n)) time.

If you don't want waste memory with a sorted set, you can use **KEYS** to return a large list of all of your keys in the cities "table".  Then, your program can iterate through these keys automatically and count how many cities have a state of 'CA'.  This is a bit of manual labor, but it will still run in O(n) time.

If you already have city data pre-populated in your database, you can generate your sorted set using **KEYS**, as well (see the method outlined above).  Hopefully that helps!

See:

- http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set
- http://redis.io/commands/keys